# How to read dynamic argument airflow operator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, yaml, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I am new in python and airflow dag.
I am following below link and code which is mention in answer section.
             [How to pass dynamic arguments Airflow operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55300453/how-to-pass-dynamic-arguments-airflow-operator)

I am facing issue to reading yaml file, In yaml file I have some configuration related arguments.

```
configs:
    cluster_name: "test-cluster"
    project_id: "t***********"
    zone: "europe-west1-c"
    num_workers: 2
    worker_machine_type: "n1-standard-1"
    master_machine_type: "n1-standard-1"
```

In DAG script I have created one task which will be create cluster, before executing this task we need all the arguments which we need to pass on it default_args parameter like cluster-name, project_id etc.For reading those parameter I have created one readYML method.see below code

```
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zipfile import ZipFile
from airflow.contrib.operators import dataproc_operator

from airflow.models import Variable
import yaml

def readYML():
     print("inside readYML")
     global cfg
     file_name = "/home/airflow/gcs/data/cluster_config.yml"
     with open(file_name, 'r') as ymlfile:
          cfg = yaml.load(ymlfile)
     print(cfg['configs']['cluster_name'])

 # Default Arguments
 readYML()

 dag_name = Variable.get("dag_name")

  default_args = {
     'owner': 'airflow',
     'depends_on_past': False,
     'start_date': datetime.now(),
     'email': ['airflow@example.com'],
     'email_on_failure': False,
     'email_on_retry': False,
     'retries': 1,
     'retry_delay': timedelta(minutes=5),
     #'cluster_name': cfg['configs']['cluster_name'],    
    }

    # Instantiate a DAG

    dag = DAG(dag_id='read_yml', default_args=default_args, 
    schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1))

    # Creating Tasks
    Task1 = DataprocClusterCreateOperator(
    task_id='create_cluster',
    dag=dag
    )
```

In this code there is no error, When I am uploading in GCP composer environment, No error notification is showing but this DAG is no runnable there is no Run button is coming.

See attached screen shot.
I am using python 3 & airflow composer-1.7.2-airflow-1.10.2 version.[image]

Comment: this usually indicates you have issue with your code that airflow cannot parse it. If you have an airflow environment setup, I suggest you try `python your_dag.py` and see if it gave you any error message. One thing I can see already is `dag=DAG` should be `dag=dag`

Comment: @Chengzhi No,Here I have done mistake in copy paste, actually creating task I have created in different python file, so from there I copied the code, anyway this kind of issue we can see in the notification alert in red color, you can see in above screenshot, there is no error. So this is not the issue I already checked

Comment: Can you verify if the airflow scheduler is running as well?

Comment: Yeah, It's running fine

Comment: Of course there is an error in the code, your line `default_args = {` is indented once space to deep. Apart from that YML](https://fdik.org/yml/) is not the same as [YAML](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2/spec.html) and the recommended extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` at least since Sep 2006. So you should constently use  YAML and `.yaml` in your code.

Comment: There is no indention error in this code I verified all, except this I tried with .yaml file as well but same error was coming.

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Data Stored in Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/concepts/cloud-storage#capacity_considerations) page in the Cloud Composer docs:

> To avoid a webserver error, make sure that data the webserver needs to parse a DAG (not run) is available in the dags/ folder. Otherwise, the webserver can't access the data or load the Airflow web interface.

Your DAG is attempting to open the YAML file under `/home/airflow/gcs/data`, which isn't present on the webserver. Put the file under the `dags/` folder in your GCS bucket, and it will be accessible to the scheduler, workers, and webserver, and the DAG will work in the Web UI.

Comment: What is the way to access any configuration file, which is not in the dag folder even not in the composer bucket. we need to access configuration file from other bucket.What will be the way ?

Comment: @BhageshArora some ways you could do this is to use the GCS-related operators, or the BashOperator with `gsutil` to pull configuration data into a DAG.

Comment: @BhageshArora The best way to access this is to save your yaml file configs in the dags folder. You can create a folder inside the dags folder specifically for this. I have had same problem. This is already as answered by Wilson above. Composer by default doesnt sync any other location apart from dags folder across workers. This is why the dags folder is recommended